# conversion of 2d array to json object in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

consider my array in nodejs as

```
[x:["xyz","abc","uvw","efg"],y:["wer","mno","sdk"]]
```

when i tried converting this array using JSON.stringify() i could get only [] in return.

is there any way to store multiple values like array in Object data type.

Comment: is it `{x:["xyz","abc","uvw","efg"],y:["wer","mno","sdk"]}` corrected ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use array with a non-numeric index. In your case you should use an object instead: `{x:["xyz","abc","uvw","efg"],y:["wer","mno","sdk"]}`.

Be aware that you can get keys of this object with `Object.keys(obj)`. It returns an array `['x', 'y']` and you can iterate through the object.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion i could proceed by using object type and assigning array to it as how you said.  Thanks Again